# Does using eval() increase memory consumption?

Tags: javascript, memory

I have written some Javascript (specifically a jQuery plugin) in which I replace the contents of some tags with the result of an eval to give me some kind of templating mechanism.

My question is: Will using eval() over and over cause a problem with memory?

The reason I ask is that when I look at the loaded scripts with Firebug, I see all the eval'ed code listed there, so my worry is that if the user uses this application in the browser, it might cause a problem with memory.

Comment: A wise man once said: if `eval()` is the answer, you definitely asked the wrong question!

Comment: Depends on your eval code. Upload some of them first.

Comment: I don't know about memory consumption, but `eval()`ed code is known to run much slower.

Comment: @spudley - only in that it needs to be parsed twice - which is usually a small overhead compared with hauling the stuff across the network / post-parsing execution.

Comment: @BenM: funny, @Starx: good idea, @Spudley: the question is about memory though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from it being a bad idea to use eval, there will almost certainly be some memory overhead in setting it up.

Also eval code won't be as optimised** as there is no chance for caching or other optimisations.

** depending on browser.

Comment: Well, I cannot really accept this answer, because the question was whether eval() increases memory consumption, and you gave me an "almost certainly", which is quite close to "maybe".

Comment: Well what do you expect with all the different types of javascript engines / browsers / ways of coding / ways of using eval ??

Comment: Do you perhaps have a link to something that explains the overhead (particularly from a memory point of view) of using eval() in any browser (even if only one)?